# Указатель this->

Tags: c++

Кто может более подробней рассказать про указатель this->. Вот маленький кусок кода:

```
#include <iostream>
class thisis{
private: int var;
public:
    thisis(int var) { this->var = var; std::cout << var; };
    void getit() { std::cout << var; };
};
int main(){
    thisis obj1(2);
    obj1.getit();
    return 0;
}
```

окей ничего сложного, самый обычный пример из книги, мы просто сделали присвоение. которое равнозначно обычному присвоению ( только с одним но, у нас две одноименные переменные и поэтому одну из них нам необходимо было переименовать ). просто указатель, который работает в классе. но смысл данного указателя, может быть у него есть другое применение?

Comment: Это старомодный синтаксис. В конструкторе `this` практически не нужен; member initializer удобнее: `thisis(var): var(var) { std::cout << var; }` . Единственное мне известное применение - в операторах присваивания: `return *this;`

Comment: @user58697 вот кстати забыл о перегрузке оператора присваивания упомянуть

Comment: Я смешно опечатался: `не` вместо `мне`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем примере можно было обойтись и без указателя `this`. Например,

```
thisis(int var) { thisis::var = var; std::cout << var; };
```

Если вам нужен пример другого применения указателя `this`, где без него не обойтись, так вот вам такой пример

```
thisis & operator = ( const thisis &rhs )
{
    var = rhs.var;

    return *this;
}
```

Внутри нестатических функций - членов класса указатель `this` указывает на объект, для которого нестатическая функция была вызвана.

Я вам уже показал пример использования `this` в операторе копирующего присваивания. Иногда в таких операторах требуется проверять, не происходит ли присваивание объекта самому себе.

Поэтому код оператора присваивания может выглядеть так

```
thisis & operator = ( const thisis &rhs )
{
    if ( this != &rhs )
    {
        //...
    }

    return *this;
}
```